# He is almost abject in his respect for his boss

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have seen the meaning of the word Abject in Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary:

> **abject** (*adj.) showing no  pride  or respect for yourself

and the example sentence in the dictionary is:

> *He is almost abject in his respect for his boss*.

Can you please let me know the meaning of the above example sentence, I am getting confused what it is saying, what its meaning with his respect for his boss? Can someone let me know the meaning of the sentence in easy sentence?

Answer (score 1):

By how he shows his respect for his boss, he is demeaning himself, almost to the extent it appears he has no respect for himself.

Answer (score 0):

He has no respect for himself when he is in front of his boss.

Comment: ...or at least you wouldn't know it by the way he behaves.

Answer (score 0):

He is so "respectful" (fearful, actually) of his boss that he has no respect for **himself** in the presence of his boss.